# Is there a way to test parity of fractional part (only period) of irredecible rational number without calculation?

Tags: fractional-part, parity

I search in the web to get any way to test parity of fractional part of irredicible rational number by means to know if that fraction (period) even or odd but i didn't get , for example  the fraction part of $\frac {17}{19}$ equal to $ \overline{894736842105263157} $ which is odd integer? Any way to test that parity without calculation ? by means how we use the fundemantal arithmitic in number theory to test parity of that period  ?

Comment: $\frac{17}{18}=0.9\overline 4$.   The decimal you quote is about $\frac {17}{19}$ and the period is even.

Comment: What is the "irrational numbers" tag doing here?

Comment: I didn't find the tag of rational number i replaced it by irrational may it include it

Comment: @RossMillikan i believe he doesn't worry about the period but rather the fractional part

Comment: @Shamim:  the fractional part is infinite.  The period is the only thing that makes sense unless you count digits that are not part of the period like the $9$ in $0.9\overline 4$

Comment: I meant he was talking of the parity of the number within each period, they just repeat themselves

Comment: @RossMillikan,I meant period not fractional part I just used fractional part as indication of the part I want in rational number

Comment: Your last comment continues to confuse me.  The period is of even length.  By odd, do you mean the last digit of the repeat is odd?  The period is the number of digits in the repeat.

Comment: I meant the parity of period as integer even or odd

Answer (score 1):

It helps to look at fractions of the form $\frac 1b$ first with $b$ not divisible by $5$.  If $b$ is odd, the repeat of the decimal will be odd.  If you think about doing the long division to compute the repeat, the last subtraction must result in a remainder of $1$ so you start back around the cycle.  That means the number subtracted from $0$ must be odd, so the last digit of the repeat must be odd.  We can even say more-the last digit $d$ of the repeat is such that $db\equiv 9 \bmod 10$, so if the last digit of $b$ is $1$, the last digit of $d$ is $9$ and so on.  The repeat for $\frac ab$ will just be the repeat for $\frac 1b$ multiplied by $a$, so will be even if $a$ is even and odd with $a$ odd.

If $b$ ends in $5$, we are really interested in $\frac 1{2b}$ because the factor $5$ will just make a leading digit before the repeat starts.  Similarly, if $b$ is even, we are interested in $\frac 1{5b}$, using the $5$ to neutralize the factor $2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , pleas raise the downvote of my question, I think it is not good  howedver the question is clear and no ambiguity in it so  to answer a question with downvote because this means that question is not  of research and the provided answer is so good and uses many teckniques